# Minimizing $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |x^2 - A|^2dx$ using Fourier Series theory

Tags: integration, optimization, fourier-analysis

> Let $f(x) = x^2$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$. Choose the real number $A$ to minimize $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)-A|^2dx$

So I see an integral with an absolute value squared term, so something like Bessel's inequality is jumping out at me. The difficultly is though that A must be a real number, so simply applying Bessel's here doesn't seem to work. My other idea was perhaps to construct a Fourier Series for A, then that should converge to a real number, and then apply Bessel's. However, I am not sure if this logic is correct.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: All you need to do is find the constant term in the series expansion, it is guaranteed to minimize the distance in $L^2$

Comment: Right, $a_0=\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2 \, dx = \frac{2\pi^2}{3},$ and the constant term is $\frac{a_0}{2} = \frac{\pi^2}{3}.$

Comment: @mjw shouldn't $a_0$ also contain $A$? or are we simply looking at the fourier series expansion for $x^2$?

Comment: As @GReyes observed, the "$A$" that minimizes the mean squared value is $A=\frac{a_0}{2}$, the constant term in the Fourier series.

Comment: Why is this the case? And is this for complex or real notation?

Comment: The reason is the orthogonality of the trigonometric system. What you want to do is minimize the distance to the subspace generated by the constant function $g_0(x)=1$. The minimum is given by the orthogonal projection  onto the subspace. But this is precisely the first partial sum of the series.

Comment: In the "answer", there is nothing special about $f(x)=x^2$, it could have been any function.  We minimize $A^2 \int dx - 2A \int f(x) dx$ which leads to $A=\frac{\int f(x) dx}{\int dx} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) dx.$

Comment: @GReyes So we want to choose $A$ is such a way that $|f-A| = c_n$, where $c_n$ are the Fourier coefficients, since is the closest approximation to $f$ (i.e. the orthogonal projection)?

Comment: @GReyes Also, what is $g_0(x) = 1$ in this case? Is it simply $|f(x) - g_0(x)A|$?

Comment: What you want is to minimize the distance to the subspace of constant functions, spanned by $g_0(x)=1$ or any other non-zero constant. This is always achieved by the orthogonal projection in any Hilbert space. Any partial sum of the Fourier series is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by $\{1,\sin x,\cos x,\sin 2x,\cos 2x,\dots\sin nx,\cos nx\}$ (this is not a normal basis, but that does not change the span). In your particular case, you need the projection onto the span of $g_0$, which is just the constant term in the series, $a_0/2$. Your $A=a_0/2$, the integral average.

Answer (score 1):

We want to minimize $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi (x^2-A)^2 dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi x^4 dx-2A \int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2 dx +  A^2 \int_{-\pi}^\pi dx$$

This is equivalent to minimizing $ A^2 \int_{-\pi}^\pi dx -2A \int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2 dx $ or $$g(A) = \frac{A^2}{2} - \frac{\pi^2 }{3}A.$$

$$g^\prime(A) = A-\frac{\pi^2}{3} = 0.$$

$$A=\frac{\pi^2}{3}.$$

It is obvious that this is at the minimum (and not the maximum).  Nevertheless $g^{\prime\prime}(A) =1 >0.$